# Mouse and keyboard not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, grub, gdm

I updated my Ubuntu Linux to 14.04 and now the mouse and keyboard don't work in the login screen. I tried re-installing grub from a Live USB, but it's still not working. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: does the keyboard work before the boot loader, when it is controlled by the BIOS ?, like to hit del, f2 or whatever to enter setup...

Comment: yes it does. It doesn't work only in login screen.

Comment: I also have installed Windows 7 Ultimate, and I don't have any problems login in that SO.

Comment: Do the Mouse and Keyboard work in a normal Terminal?  Press Ctrl + Alt + F3 at the login screen, then try logging in.

Comment: I press Ctrl + Alt + F3 at the login screen but doesn't work.

Comment: Please move this to a comment. I do not have sufficient rep. I have the same problem. Are the instructions to be done whilst running the LIVE USB. Since the keyboard doesn't work I can't see another way.

Comment: just do it one thing backup your data and install newer version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I had the problem, which was solved by installing the linux-image-extra-xxx package.

Answer (score 18):

Reinstall input device drivers

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all
```

Comment: I just did it, but still not working.

Comment: Have you updated your system with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` ? I found there was some bug that could cause it.

Comment: How can she do that if she can't login?

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I try update and upgrade booting with a ubuntu live ubs. But it still not working.

Comment: Can you login with recovery mode? When grub is showing list of options, there should be recovery mode for ubuntu.

Comment: recovery mode, drop to shell

Comment: I see a cursor briefly as the GUI is initialized then when the desktop, icons, etc appears, nothing. No ability to use keyboard either. How could the above update/upgrade and re-install not work, yet something in recovery mode will?  I was able to do the above updates using boot to another kernel (not recovery but something else) yet, no effect!

Answer (score 3):

half-way fix: reboot, choose in boot menu older kernel, boot it. keyboard and mouse works. then you can login and fix your configs. 
ps: if you can not boot anymore (cause you kill your grub) then only one way to fix: you must make boot usb flash drive and boot from it. then mopunt your HDD and backup/fix your configs.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I also followed the link https://groups.google.com/a/linux.ie/forum/#!topic/ilug/d4mtWuD9aF0 and after logging in with old kernel, I issued `apt-get update`, `apt-get dist-upgrade`, `update-usbids` and something of it made the keyboard and mouse work on new kernel too.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode), hold shift after the BIOS loads.

Select the second kernel with (recovery mode). If you still have the same problem, mouse/keyboard not responding then reboot and try again with the next available recovery mode kernal. I have once had to use the third option before it worked.

Turn on networking `network` then fix the packages `dpkg`. Once complete `resume`.
The video drivers may be wonky, either way reboot.

Keyboard and mouse should be working again.

Comment: What if no options work?

Comment: Unable to start network, therefore dpkg doesn't work !!